# How to use a tablet as a second screen?

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

A few months ago I was able to use RDP to use my tablet screen as a second screen to my Ubuntu 22.04. However, I'm unable to achieve the same now.

After several hours of looking around on the web, I've seen several [tutorials](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/use-ipad-as-second-monitor-ubuntu-22-04) that do what I want to. I'm unable to get it to work though.

I'm able to login to a user that's not currently logged in on my laptop but I want to login as the user that's logged in on my laptop so that the tablet becomes a wireless monitor just like Samsung's `Second Screen` for windows.

I found [this](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2491) that seems to be the reason why I won't be able to login as the same user. To overcome this restriction, I've tried [few approaches](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16698) but haven't had any luck.

I'm also unable to login with the credentials at `Settings>Sharing>Remote Desktop`, it just says `login failed for display 0`. This happens only with RDP, VNC works but that just mirrors my display.

Given below are the entries from `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`

```
[20240226-21:48:18] [INFO ] Socket 8: AF_INET6 connection received from ::1 port 57504
[20240226-21:48:20] [ERROR] pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
[20240226-21:48:21] [INFO ] Username or password error for user: cm
[20240226-21:48:21] [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
[20240226-21:48:21] [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans
```

How do I get my tablet to work as a second screen?